# Where can I find the specific contract implementation for the part __unstable__ERC20Owned?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/90ed1af972299070f51bf4665a85da56ac4d355e/contracts/GSN/GSNRecipientERC20Fee.sol

Where can I find the specific contract implementation for the part _*unstable__ERC20Owned where "" "* token = new __unstable__ERC20Owned (name, symbol);" "" in the above url?

There should be a file defined as a type because it is used for "using".
If this (__unstable__ERC20Owned) is not a contract, where can I find its concrete implementation?
Or there is no concrete implementation Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_unstable__ERC20Owned` is a contract. You can find it in your file at the line 118.

A same file can include several contracts.

For exemple here you have two contracts in the same file : `GSNRecipientERC20Fee` and `_unstable__ERC20Owned`. The first one instantiates the second one in its constructor.